# How can I send feedback on Windows Phone and apps / services directly to Microsoft?

Tags: feedback

Is there an official way to send feedback on Windwos Phone in general and specific apps like Cortana or Xbox Music directly to Microsoft?

Comment: @RareNCool FYI, the "untagged" tag cannot be added manually by users. It's generally added when the question's existing tags are removed or if the question is migrated to another Stack Exchange site that doesn't have the tag(s) the question had on the original site. Re-tagging such questions is of course the appropriate course of action.

Comment: @Indrek Ah, good to know! I thought it seemed a little weird to tag a question as "untagged", but hey...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 10 Mobile there is a Windows Feedback app for reporting feedback on MS services and apps. There you can submit, vote, filter, and search for feedback. All other feedback should be given via ratings and reviews in the Store.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft manages several [UserVoice](https://www.uservoice.com/) sites for Windows Phone and it's different services:

- [<s>Windows Phone</s>](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com)
- [Windows Phone Developer](https://wpdev.uservoice.com)
- [Xbox Music](https://xboxmusic.uservoice.com)
- [<s>Cortana</s>](https://cortana.uservoice.com/)
- [<s>Lumia Beta Apps</s>](https://lumiabetaapps.uservoice.com)
- [OneNote](https://onenote.uservoice.com/)

Comment: It's worth noting that a few of these sites have been shut down. (For sure Windows Phone and Lumia Beta Apps, can't check Xbox Music at the moment.)

Comment: I marked the ones that are not in use anymore.